# Is there any .apk maker on android phone?

Tags: android, apk

I wonder if there is any apk-maker that runs on android phone to make an apk native on the phone without the need of using a PC?
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can code in Android on an Android, see below AIDE for coding.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en

I don't think it is very productive though! Good luck!